# Visual Studio TFS merge dialog is slow to appear for the option "Selected Changesets"

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

When using Visual Studio and TFS (version is 2015, though I believe this issue is in all versions), and you want to merge selected changesets from one branch to another, it can take a very long time for the Merge dialog to appear.

In researching this issue, I found a stored procedure in the Tfs_DefaultCollection database called prc_PendMerge that is called to retrieve items for the Merge dialog.  In our case this returns about 1.5 million rows from the tbl_Version table, and resources consist of 15 million SQL reads, over 100,000 CPU, and the duration takes around 3 minutes.

I discovered that 95% of the rows in the tbl_Version are for the file **AssemblyInfo.xx**.  We use TFS to automatically build our solution, which consists of around 300 projects, with automatic version increments.  So each build adds 300 rows to the tbl_Version table.

As a test, I made a direct modification to the prc_PendMerge to exclude these files and was able to reduce the Merge dialog time down to around 10 seconds.  However, this is probably not the proper way to fix this issue, so I am looking to see if there is a better route.

Is there any way to truncate the version history of all these AssemblyInfo.xx files while leaving just the current version?  I was hoping the tf.exe utility might have some kind of /truncatehistory command, but I could not find one.

Also, I am aware that one can speed this up by performing the Merge on individual subfolders.  However, that doesn't really help because I usually have to merge changesets that cover multiple sub-folders simultaneously.

Comment: It seems you have a performance issue. But this issue can't be reproduced on my side. Please try to create a light project to see whether you'll reproduce this issue.

Comment: New projects work fine.  This issue exists when one needs to merge code from the trunk of a project to a branched project, and the trunk has over 1.5 million rows in the tbl_Version table.  If you look at that stored procedure, you'll see where it performs a left outer join to itself, which is where I found the slowdown occurs.  The only way to speed it up is to reduce the rows.  When I exclude rows pertaining to AssemblyInfo (which is 95% of the checkins), the statement executes in 10 seconds.